# Create UITableViewCell constraints to match with built-in cells and avoid "fixed width constraints my cause clipping."

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

In my UITableViews I have a mixture of built-in cells and custom cells that mimic the look of built-in cells. For example, I use Left Detail Cell UITableViewCells as well as custom cells that also LOOK like a Left Detail Cell but have custom elements (like a left UILabel, but a textfield instead of the right UILabel and maybe other elements like a checkmark image to let the user know when they have entered valid info).

I originally set up the constraints on my custom cells so that blue left-side label would have a width constraint = 91 because that is what the built-in cell's label's width was.

However, for the last few versions of Xcode, it has been complaining at me about "Fixed width constraints may cause clipping."

I've seen all of the myriad Stack Overflow posts telling me to just make my constraint <= or >=, but that does NOT do what I want. I don't want those labels to get bigger, because then the various rows will not have a consistent width on those left detail labels. The screenshot below wouldn't have a consistent layout from row to row.

So, how can I set my constraints on that left detail UILabel so that it will match with the built-in Left Detail Cell's sizing behaviors without getting that stupid warning clogging up my build results?

I tried setting a proportional width on the label, but when I rotate the device my label gets much wider while the built-in Left Detail cell's detail label stays the same width and my UI looks janky because they aren't lined up anymore.

I tried making my fixed width constraint a lower priority (750) and adding a second <= constraint at priority 1000, but then it just complained about both constraints.

Example below:

[image]